# Nginx in docker routing multiple applications

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have 3 apps that are located in 3 different sites:

1. auth (localhost:59500)
2. manage (localhost:59501)
3. files (localhost:59502)

Manage and files are accessed from a menu in auth

I can access them individually. However, I am unsure of how to set this up in nginx.

This is what I have currently in my nginx conf:

```
upstream auth {
    server auth.web;
}
upstream manage {
    server manage.web;
}
upstream files {
    server files.web;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";


    location /{
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
        proxy_pass http://auth/;
    }
    location /auth/{
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
        proxy_pass http://auth/;
    }
    location /manage/{
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
        proxy_pass http://manage/;
    }

    location /files/{
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
        proxy_pass http://files/;
    }
}
```

My nginx is configured to run on http://localhost:9190

Currently, when I run http://localhost:9190, I get to auth without any issue and am able to login.

However, if I try to access http://localhost:9190/manage/Home, I am able to load the page but all my css shows the error 404. If any error appears, it doesnt go back to http://localhost:9190/manage/Home. Instead, it kicks me back to http://localhost:9190/Home

EDIT:

I have tried this but my css and js scripts still aren't loading. However, I am able to navigate to the manage app

```
location ^~ /manage{
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    proxy_pass http://manage/manage;
}
location ^~ /manage/{
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    proxy_pass http://manage/manage/;
}
```

EDIT2:

I realized that the error css and js files had a Content-Type of text/html

The files that managed to load somehow had application/javascript or text/css

Not sure how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the answer. There were two changes that needed to happen.

In my webapp, I needed to set a Pathbase in my Startup

app.UsePathBase("/manage");

Then in Nginx,

I needed to set the name in the location like this:

```
location /Manage/{
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    proxy_pass http://manage_svr/Manage/;
}
```